# WordPress is executing URL in code when called via wp_mail()

Tags: custom-post-types, php, wp-mail, email-verification

I have written a custom plugin (that creates a custom post type) and allows any user to submit a new post from a form on my website. To prevent bots, I have setup an e-mail confirmation code which they must click, where this changes the post status from Draft to Published.

Unfortunately the `wp_mail()` code shown below seems to be executing this confirmation URL automatically. As soon as the post is submitted, it is set to Draft until it reaches this code, and then it automatically publishes.

Removing this block makes everything work as expected. Does anyone have any idea as to the reason and how to fix it?

```
$confirm_url = site_url(). '/verification?id=' . $post_id . '&hash=' . $hash;

// Send a verification e-mail to the user to confirm publication
$subject = 'Please confirm your Slicer Profile submission';
$body = $confirm_url;
wp_mail( $profile_email, $subject, $body );
```

Comment: It is not clear at all what does "executed" means, and whether it has anything to do with wordpress.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. When the link stored in $confirm_url is ran (i.e. /verification?id=1234&hash=abc123xyzd) it changes the post status from Draft to Publish. This is not supposed to happen until the user clicks the link in their e-mail, but this code block is making that happen automatically. As in, when this wp_mail code block is there, it publishes immediately.

Comment: I updated the explanation in my original post to make it more clear.

Comment: will phrase what I meant differently. How do you know that your code puts it in a draft in the first place, and how do you know it is not the email client that "runs" the link?

Comment: ... you have decided what is the problem with no supporting evidance that that is actually the problem

Comment: Basically if I remove that exact code block in the original post, submissions always get inserted as Draft. As soon as I add that block back, they are Published immediately when submitted.

Comment: enable debug mode and see the error

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4sxZnXyF That is the full plugin code, with the relevant function being lines 239-292

Comment: @VisakhBSujathan Wordpress debug or just the wp_mail() error logging?

Comment: it make very little sense. wp_mail do not do such things, if the other parts of the code are correct than there is some external utility that does it.

Comment: both Wordpress debug and the wp_mail() error logging.then only we can know  the reason

Comment: @VisakhBSujathan I enabled WP_DEBUG and dumped the results of wp_mail() but nothing. All I get is the result of wp_mail() which is true. There aren't any errors because everything is working right, something is just changing the post status from Draft -> Publish and I can't figure out what.

Comment: Updated my answer, pretty sure it's the unescaped-slash in your single-quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following, I think having a return from the `site_url()` function could be creating a problem with the `$confirm_url` variable.

That and you have an unescaped slash in your url.

```
$site_url = site_url();
$confirm_url = $site_url. '\/verification?id=' . $post_id . '&hash=' . $hash;

// Send a verification e-mail to the user to confirm publication
$subject = 'Please confirm your Slicer Profile submission';
$body = $confirm_url;
wp_mail( $profile_email, $subject, $body );
```

You might need to switch to magic-quotes too, ie:

```
$site_url = site_url();
$confirm_url = "{$site_url}/verification?id={$post_id}&hash={$hash}";

// Send a verification e-mail to the user to confirm publication
$subject = "Please confirm your Slicer Profile submission";
$body = $confirm_url;
wp_mail( $profile_email, $subject, $body );
```

The parenthesis around the variables in the double-quotes aren't necessary, but some devs find them easier to read in long strings.

Comment: This is actually being used in the main php file of a custom plugin. The wp_mail() and site_url() functions are working. For some reason, the url specified for $confirm_url just seems to be getting ran with that code block (i.e. they don't need to click it themselves)

Comment: Forgot to note, if I remove that block of code, everything works as expected (minus them receiving an e-mail of course). The custom post type is inserted and set to "Draft", then just waits for confirmation. So everything is good except something in that code block is executing the URL.

Comment: no no no no no. you should never guess the location of where wordpress is installed. Instead you should write a proper plugin that will process a form (or however else the info is sent)

Comment: @MarkKaplun All of my data is coming from a form, the code block I provided is the tail end of the handler. This bit just sends the user the confirmation e-mail after inserting the post into the DB and setting the status to Draft (it's supposed to change to Published once they click that, but this block of code is automatically doing that for some reason)

Comment: I see your point @MarkKaplun but if the functionality isn't going to be distributed, what's the problem with anticipating `wp-load.php` being 3 folders up from where a plugin containing a non-WordPress file is located? If I'm creating a single plugin for a single private site... How is this a liability? I prefer to do things that way because then the integration-script (wether it's for an api-post, db-save, or what have you) is simpler to port over to other platforms because it's agnostic php.

Comment: @admcfajn I do not mean it in a bad way, but pro people do not write amateur code even for a one off quick tasks. There are right ways and wrong ways, and people that have been around enough time have been beaten enough by that "it has no chance to make a difference" attitude to just never have it again.

Comment: ... and in the context of this site, we are setting an example to thousands of people that will be sure that this is a good thing to do.

Comment: Completely understand @MarkKaplun. Doing so involves importing a wordpress-core file into an unknown environment which is the running within WordPress. Not good. It would be better to use an `admin_post` hook instead of a stand-alone file. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action) (I've just done a lot of different form-integrations over the years and recalled that hack). We'll see if my new answer does the trick.

Comment: Holy hell, I think that was actually it. I tried your second code block first and the problem persisted (it was weird, went to draft for about 15 seconds, then was published when I refreshed the page). The first code block however seems to have actually fixed it... trying a few more posts to make sure but wow... thank you so so much.

Comment: Well it seems that fixed it. Don't know that I would have ever caught that but thank you so much. The first code block works and all post submissions stay in Draft status now.